# Writing Kafka streaming RDD into Oracle DB in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying to load data from kafka stream into Oracle RDBMS and hive the messages in Hive are getting written properly but records are missing while loading into Oracle.

Below is snippet of my code. The window of Spark streaming is of 1 sec.

```
rowRDD.foreachPartition(new VoidFunction<Iterator<String () {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;                                       

    @Override
              public void call(Iterator<String> rowIterator) throws Exception { 

                           //prepared statement query                                 
                          String sql = "insert into  " + tableName + " (TRANS_AMOUNT,) values (?, ?)";

                          Connection connection = null;
                          PreparedStatement ps = null;

                        try {

                             connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcDatabaseUrl, jdbcUsername, jdbcPassword);
                             ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

                          int count = 0;

                          RowTemplate message = new RowTemplate();                  

                          while (rowIterator.hasNext() ) {
                             String recordRow = rowIterator.next();

                             if (recordRow != null && !recordRow.equals("")) { 

                                //populate message object properties
                                message.setProperties(recordRow,kafkaRecorddelimiter);       

                                java.util.Date transDate = formatter.parse(trnsDateTime);
                                Timestamp transactionDate = new Timestamp(transDate.getTime());                         

                                String transAmount = message.getTransactionAmount() ;                            
                                ps.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(transAmount);                                      
                                ps.setTimestamp(2, transactionDate);

                                ps.addBatch();                          

                               if(++count % batchSize == 0) 

                                    ps.executeBatch();

                             }
                             message.clearProperties();

                          }
                          ps.executeBatch(); // insert remaining records


  }
```

Comment: Have you considered using Kafka Connect for this? It's part of Apache Kafka, and specifically designed for streaming data from Kafka topics into RDBMS, HDFS/Hive, Elasticsearch, etc etc

Comment: @Robin Thanks for your reply, at the moment I need this thing working, not able to figure out where the records are getting dropped

Comment: What do you mean "get it working"? Only data into Oracle (with proven patterns and code written and used **by others** using Kafka Connect), or debugging **your own** Spark code and hope it runs efficiently on your Spark Cluster? By the way, `forEachPartition` should be avoided here, and you need to establish the JDBC connection `forEachRDD` instead... Besides, if you have a DataFrame, then you are missing out on one line of `df.write.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:oracle...")...save()`